# AngularJS file upload Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-fileupload

I am trying to do a file upload using angularjs. But I am getting this error for the past few days and I am unable to resolve:

> angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=fileUploadServiceProvider%20%3C-%20fileUploadService%20%3C-%20appCtrl
>
> ```
> at angular.js:38
> at angular.js:4511
> at Object.d [as get] (angular.js:4664)
> at angular.js:4516
> at d (angular.js:4664)
> at e (angular.js:4688)
> at Object.invoke (angular.js:4710)
> at S.instance (angular.js:10354)
> at p (angular.js:9263)
> at g (angular.js:8620)
> ```

I only want to read the files uploaded, and store it in the server, and not to link to other URL. I am using Django for my backend. This are my codes:

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
        <input type="file" id="file" name="files" accept="text/*"
               data-url="file" class="upload" ng-model="uploadFile"/>
        <label for="file">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open" id="selectFile">
          </span>Select a file
        </label>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="../static/js/services/fileUploadService.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/controllers/fileUploadController.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/fileModel.js"></script>
```

Directives:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.directive("filesInput", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = elem[0].files;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Service

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.factory('fileUploadService', function ($rootScope) {
    var _files = [];

    var service = {
        add: add,
        clear: clear,
        upload: upload,
      }

     return service 

     function add(file){
        _files.push(file)
        $rootScope.$broadcast('fileAdded', file.files[0].name)
      }
      function clear(){
        _files = []
      }
      function upload(){
        _files.submit();        
      }
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, fileUploadService){
    $scope.$watch('uploadFile', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
        //clear existing files
        fileUploadService.clear()
        if(newVal == true){
            var formdata = new FormData();
            $scope.getTheFiles = function ($files) {
                angular.forEach($files, function (value, key) {
                    formdata.append(key, value);
                });
            };    
            // NOW UPLOAD THE FILES.
            $scope.uploadFile = function () {    
                var request = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: file,
                    data: formdata,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                    }
                };    
                // SEND THE FILES.
                $http(request)
                    .success(function (d) {
                        alert(d);
                    })
                    .error(function () {
                    });
            }
        }]);
        fileUploadService.add(newVal)
        fileUploadService.upload()
    }
})
```

Comment: Is `app` declared somewhere? I only see `uploadComponent` module

Comment: You didn't show the relevant part - The error say that the `fileUploadService` service was not found. Probably because you didn't add it to your app's dependencies

Comment: @AlonEitan It's actually in my script, which I've forgot to show. I've added them.

Comment: @BillP yes, controller, service and directive all have `var app = angular.module('myApp', [])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
```

it creates a new module, so controller, service and directive are registered in a separate module! This results in the injection error as controller cannot inject the service, as it is registered in a different module.

The solution is to only create one module and register all the other components in it, like this:

1st file:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp').factory('fileUploadService', function ($rootScope) {
   ... 
});
```

2nd file

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, fileUploadService){
  ...
});
```

3rd file:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive("filesInput", function() {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Also, after the first script with `var app = angular.module('myApp', [])` it can be written like `var app = angular.module('myApp'); app.directive("filesInput", function() {});` and so on for services and components.

Comment: what do you mean by "register all the other components in it"? so I create directive, controller, and service in one page? sorry, I'm new to angularjs.

Comment: @lealceldeiro so I don't need to declare `var app = angular.module('myApp', [])` again for all?

Comment: @user3774763, no you don't. Just after the first call to `angular.module('myApp', [])` (creating the module), you can simply do `angular.module('myApp').directive|factory|component|<any-other>`... this will locate the module and create whatever you put after: a factory, directive, etc

Comment: They can be in separate files as they already are.But you have to create the application module(app) only once, as lealceldeiro describes

Comment: Take a look at this [module declaration](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gmsboilerplate/blob/3a6fb4948bf5575054bd62ef3c9420534985662c/grails-app/assets/client/app/app.module.js#L232) and after that, all other declarations exclude the `[]`, for example, [home.ctrl](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gmsboilerplate/blob/3a6fb4948bf5575054bd62ef3c9420534985662c/grails-app/assets/client/app/modules/home/home.ctrl.js#L10), [user.srv](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gmsboilerplate/blob/master/grails-app/assets/client/app/modules/admin/account/user/user.srv.js#L10) and so on.

Comment: It should work.. Maybe you should edit the answer with the latest changes

Comment: done, what I've edited are my current codes now @BillP

Comment: does it matter which file should contain `var app = angular.module('myApp', [])`?

Comment: @user3774763, yes, it matters. That file should be the first one to be loaded.

Comment: my controller actually contains more than 1 service: e.g. `app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, fileUploadService, Service2, Service3....){` previously, it was working fine. I'm afraid if I were to change the position of `var app = angular.module('myApp', [])` it may destroy my code.

Comment: @user3774763, please provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you better. Use stackblitz, codepen, or any similar. It's being really hard to give you an accurate solution with the current info.

Answer (score 1):

### Avoid multiple statements that create the module.

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
> app.directive("filesInput", function() {
>   //...
> });
>
> var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
> app.factory('fileUploadService', function ($rootScope) {
>   //...
> }};
>
> var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
> app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, fileUploadService){
>   //...
> });
> ```

The extra `angular.module('myApp', [])` statements are overwriting existing modules, resulting in the `fileUploadService` becoming unregistered.

BETTER

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

angular.module('myApp').directive("filesInput", function() {
  //...
});

angular.module('myApp').factory('fileUploadService', function ($rootScope) {
  //...
}};

angular.module('myApp').controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, fileUploadService){
  //...
});
```

The statement creating the module must be placed before all the code adding more entities to it.

From the Docs:

> ## Creation versus Retrieval
>
> Beware that using `angular.module('myModule', [])` will create the module `myModule` and **overwrite any existing module named `myModule`.** Use `angular.module('myModule')` to retrieve an existing module.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Modules - Creation versus Retrieval](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval)
- [AngularJS angular.module Function API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)